# Is there an app or website that evaluates individual hotel rooms?

Tags: online-resources, hotels

I just heard on the radio of an app, that where [seat guru](http://www.seatguru.com) evaluates the seat in an airplane, they give hotel evaluations on individual rooms. This app would tell you for example when you would not sleep in a specific hotel room because of the constant elevator movements.

I was driving in very dense traffic, so I could not note its name. So I know it exists, but I completely forgot its name.

Does anyone know about which app I am talking?

Answer (score 8):

I think you mean [Room 77](https://www.room77.com/) app...

Answer (score 1):

[Tripadvisor hotel Reviews](http://www.tripadvisor.com) are actually quite good for this. While not exhaustive, the 'tips' section is invaluable in pointing out it, for example, one side of the hotel will have excessive noise from a nearby highway. Additionally, user submitted photos are fairly good for checking out the layout/furnishing of various room offerings to catch hidden dealbreakers like a cramped bathroom or lack of a work desk.